# How could I change NbDialogService size?

Tags: angular, nebular

I'm opening a Dialog Service, using Nebular Template.

I'm using:

```
this.dialogService.open(FormModalComponent, {
  context: {
    title: title,
  },
});
```

To open the dialog and change the text of the title.

How could I change the size of the dialog window ?

Comment: have you found a solution in the meantime? If yes, please share! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add styles for your FormModalComponent and set it height via CSS. For example:
nb-dialog-container{
width: 80rem;

```
   nb-card{
       margin: auto;
       max-height: 90vh;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation. You can do something like this :

in your component add the following:

`import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';`

below style inside component decorator:

`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`

```
this.modalService.open(ModalComponent, { size: 'lg', container: 'nb-layout' });

.modal-lg { max-width: 1490px !important; }
```

Comment: Hi, I found this solution, but actually is for modalService, not for dialogService. I've tried your solution, and i received:

 ERROR in src/app/pages/rule-manager/regras/regras.component.ts(45,7): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ size: string; container: string; context: { title: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<NbDialogConfig<string | Partial<FormModalComponent>>>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'size' does not exist in type 'Partial<NbDialogConfig<string | Partial<FormModalComponent>>>'.

Comment: this.dialogService.open(FormModalComponent, {
      size: 'lg',
      container: 'nb-layout',
      context: {
        title: title,
      },
    });

Argument of type '{ size: string; container: string; context: { title: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<NbDialogConfig<string | Partial<FormModalComponent>>>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'size' does not exist in type 'Partial<NbDialogConfig<string | Partial<FormModalComponent>>>'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 0):

You can add styles for your `FormModalComponent` and set it height via CSS. For example:

```
:host {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to dialog service like: dialogClass: 'model-full'

```
this.dialogService.open(FormModalComponent, {
  context: {
    title: title,
  }, dialogClass: 'model-full'
});
```

And a custom CSS like below:

```
.model-full {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;

  .cdk-visually-hidden {
    width: 99% !important;
    height: 99% !important;
  }

  nb-dialog-container {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Also add same class 'model-full' on card like below.

```
<div class="card model-full">
  <div class="card-header">Some Heading</div>
  <div class="card-body">

  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-right">

  </div>
</div>
```